# Remove un-/signedness of char type

Tags: c++, type-traits

I want to specialize a class template for char, short, long and long long. This specializations should also holds good for the signed and unsigned variants of the integral types.

I know boost library and std::tr1 / C++0x implements is_signed/is_unsigned and make_signed/make_unsigned type_traits. But how can I remove any signed specification from the char type (note: the only integral type where signed itype != itype)?

Comment: Why would you need something like this? If you are doing some mathematical computations, then just use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "sign-ness" of `char` is implementation defined. It doesn't have to be able to store negative numbers. In strict standardese, `char` even is *never* a signed integer type, even if it can store negative numbers on an implementation. Still, the class template `is_signed` will report `true` for `char` if it can store negative numbers, because that's a useful thing for it to do.

Anyway, the boost docs say the following about `make_unsigned`, making it look like you can use it for your purpose.

> If T is a unsigned integer type then the same type as T, if T is an signed integer type then the corresponding unsigned type. Otherwise if T is an enumerated or character type (char or wchar_t) then an unsigned integer type with the same width as T

Comment: Still, it is very simple to write a template that will remove the `signed` or `unsigned` from the char type by using two specializations for those particular types. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @David I can't really make sense of the question, so reading it like "I want to change char to unsigned char, to remove any signed-ness" is how I interpret it. Certainly your reading of the question looks reasonable too.

Comment: It is good that you have decided to *undelete* the post, the information here --whether the correct interpretation is one or the other-- is actually valuable.

Answer (score 4):

Quite manual and hardly any magic going on, but if you want to remove the `signed`/`unsigned` from a `char`, you can use this template:

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_sign_from_char {
   typedef T type;
};
template <>
struct remove_sign_from_char<signed char>
{
   typedef char type;
};
template <>
struct remove_sign_from_char<unsigned char>
{
   typedef char type;
};

int main() {
   static_assert( std::is_same< char, remove_sign_from_char<unsigned char>::type >::value );
   static_assert( std::is_same< char, remove_sign_from_char<signed char>::type >::value );
   static_assert( std::is_same< char, remove_sign_from_char<char>::type >::value );
   static_assert( std::is_same< int, remove_sign_from_char<int>::type >::value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/make_unsigned.html) `make_unsigned` should still work even on char.  Did you find otherwise?  If on your platform `char` is equivalent to `unsigned char` then it will only have an effect on the explicit `signed char` type, which is what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a quite good looking solution:

```
template<typename itype, typename = void> struct my_typedef;
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

template<>
struct my_typedef<char>
{
    typedef char          type;
    typedef signed char   signed_type;
    typedef unsigned char unsigned_type;
}; /* template<> struct my_typedef<char> */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

template<>
struct my_typedef<short>
{
    typedef short          type;
    typedef signed short   signed_type;
    typedef unsigned short unsigned_type;
}; /* template<> struct my_typedef<short> */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

template<>
struct my_typedef<long>
{
    typedef long          type;
    typedef signed long   signed_type;
    typedef unsigned long unsigned_type;
}; /* template<> struct my_typedef<long> */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

template<>
struct my_typedef<long long>
{
    typedef long long          type;
    typedef signed long long   signed_type;
    typedef unsigned long long unsigned_type;
}; /* template<> struct my_typedef<long long> */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

template<>
struct my_typedef<signed char>
{
    typedef my_typedef<char>::type          type;
    typedef my_typedef<char>::signed_type   signed_type;
    typedef my_typedef<char>::unsigned_type unsigned_type;
}; /* template<> struct my_typedef<signed char> */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

template<typename itype>
struct my_typedef<itype, typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<itype>, void>::type>
{
    typedef typename my_typedef<typename std::make_signed<itype>::type>::type type;
    typedef typename my_typedef<typename std::make_signed<itype>::type>::type signed_type;
    typedef typename my_typedef<typename std::make_signed<itype>::type>::type unsigned_type;
}; /* template<typename> struct my_typedef<signed itype> */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do here... the last template specialization is basically saying `std::is_same< unsigned int, my_typedef< unsigned int >::unsigned >::value == false`? If that was intentional, then it is at the very least misleading: `my_typedef<...>::unsigned` being a signed type.